# Random array sorting with 10,000,000

Tags: c, arrays

I must sort an array but I have a problem:

So, I made this:

```
#define size 10000000

int main() {
int arr[size], i, j;
int aux = 0;
int num;`

srand(time(NULL));

for (i = 0; i < size; i ++)
{
       num = rand() % size + 1;
       arr[i] = num;
}

for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
{

    for (j = 0; j < size-1; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
        {
            aux = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j+1];
            arr[j+1] = aux;
        }
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
}

return 0; }
```

What is the most efficient method to do that? Quick sort? What should I do? Help please in advance.

Comment: Take the array outside of `main` so it will have static storage class. Or mark it as `static`. So it won't overflow your stack.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is "not working" exactly? Do you have any error messages? It's useful to include that in the question: you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46528808/edit) it and add that.

Comment: And yeah, bubble-sorting such an array would be a pain. I guess it won't finish in an observable time.

Comment: Tried to google "sorting algorithms"?

Comment: You only have to count it only if you finally display it. like [this](https://ideone.com/BGjkFt) (Of course you can store it instead of displaying it.)

Comment: As others have mentioned, bubble sort is terrible and will take (literally) forever for an input of this size.  If you want something that's much better but still just as easy to understand and implement as bubble sort, try "Shell sort" (also known as "gap sort").  This can be thought of as a generalization of bubble sort, when you first bubble elements that are more widely separated, not necessarily always adjacent as in classic bubble sort.  (In the literature, you'll see much talk about optimal gap sequences.  Don't worry about that; just start your gap at N/2, and halve it each time.)

Answer (score 1):

Considering the input size few things can be said clearly.

10^7 inputs when sorted using bubble sort on average it would take 10^14 comparisons. Now 10^8 comparisons can be done in almost in 1 second in standard machine. So this would take a huge time.(Bubble sort is `O(n^2)`)

You have to look for some `O(nlogn)` algorithm. (To have best space and time complexity both). Maybe quicksort or merge sort or heapsort.

At this position the best would be to do a quicksort. It won't have the space complexxity as in mergesort or heapsort. <strike>So it would be the most efficient solution in this case.</strike>

As mentioned in comment Heapsort is also possible to be done in place with no extra memory with the benfit that avergae complexity will `nlogn` (theta nlogn) So heapsort  might be a good choice in this case. **Lee Daniel Crocker** mentioned it in comment.

To get rid of getting a stackoverflow as **Eugene** said you can mark the main as `static` or make the array global. That would make it not part of the stack. Also as you have mentioned using dynamic memory allocation is another option. Try allocating(`malloc()`) and `free`-ing inside `main()`.

---

To clarify further the worst case space complexity in quick sort is of the order of `nlogn` due to the stack frame in the call stack. For heap sort it is not reuquired.

Comment: I'd recommend a heapsort, personally. Much simpler than quicksort, no worst-case behavior, very educational.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker.: But yes you have to heapify it so storage is required. But yes it wont hurt to mplement heapsort. It's now a space time tradeoff.

Comment: Heapifying requires no extra space.

Comment: Heapsort can be done in-place with no extra storage.

Comment: @Dúthomhas.: Oh yes...I see...you just need to swap the elements from one by one from leaves to root. I guess... I will modify my answer.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker.: I missed the part I guess...check it now

Comment: Heapsort and Quicksort are both good options performance-wise.  Quicksort has the advantage in average performance, but as this seems to be for an assignment, I personally would use the Heapsort as it is relatively simple to implement.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons.: Yes later I have just mentioned about the space complexity. Quicksort has average complexity of nlogn same as heapsort. How do you think of performance? moreover qsort has worst case time complexity of O(n^2) but hsort is not.

Comment: quicksort does have a bad worst-case complexity which it only hits in the case that it is already mostly-sorted.  Heapsort's big weakness is the lack of data locality.  As the amount of data grows, the amount of space between elements being operated on will grow resulting in more cache misses which will hurt performance.

Comment: Yes true. That's a good point to note.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the most efficient method to do that?

OP uses `for(i = 0; i < size; i++) { for (j = 0; j < size-1; j++)` which  has on  `O(N*N)` run time.

---

OP can take advantage that this is not a general sort, (use `qsort()` for that - it is usually `O(N*log2N()`), but an array of N values with values in the range [1...N].

Instead: (similar to [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46528808/random-array-sorting-with-10-000-000#comment80013125_46528808) comment).

Given code has an array `A` of `N` elements ranging from [1...N]

Create axillary  array `B` of `N` elements initialize with 0.

Make 1 pass though `A` recording in `B` the number of occurrences of each value (offset by 1).

Make 1 pass though `B` and populate `A` per the number of times a value occurred.

Result: **`O(N)`** - Much faster.  Did use 2x memory.

---

Example

```
N = 10
A[] { 8 7 6 8 7 6 5 3 10 9 }
B[] { 0 0 1 0 1 2 2 2 1 1 } // 3 occurs once, 6 occurs twice
A[] { 3 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 10 }
```

---

Implementation note

`int arr[size]` may exceed platform's memory for a locale variable.  Consider allocating memory (or weak 2nd choice: use a global). [@ Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46528808/random-array-sorting-with-10-000-000#comment80012085_46528808)